# Public Method 'xxx' is never used

Tags: android

I have a class which extends LinearLayout. This class has a method called addSubview and the warning message "Method 'actionXYZ' is never used" shows, but the method have public modifier!

Furthermore, this method does not appear when this class is instantiated in a activity, for example.

Why?

```
public class dummyLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    RelativeLayout rootItem;

    public dummyLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public dummyLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public dummyLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context ctx) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        rootItem = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dummyLayout, this, true);
    }

    public void addSubView(View v) {
        rootItem.addView(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the method does not appear"? If it's not used by your code you'll see the information that it's not used. It's a code quality inspection designed to avoid code that isn't used.

Comment: Well I presume this is not a library and so if it's not used within the app, then it's not used full stop.